# What's the analog of requests.get in Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, python-requests

I am currently using `requst.get()` then convert it to an `HttpResponse` of `django.http`
but I expect DFR to have something for getting an `HttpResponse` at once.

full code is

```
def site(request, site_url):
    response = requests.get(site_url)

    http_response = HttpResponse(
        content=response.content,
        status=response.status_code,
        content_type=response.headers['Content-Type']
    )

    return http_response
```

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/api-clients/#python-client-library

Comment: Could you please specify what at that link could help to solve the problem

Comment: `client = coreapi.Client()` but haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

When using Django Rest Framework, you no longer need to use Django's HttpResponse. Instead, you should utilize the Response class provided by the rest framework. Import it as shown in the code snippet below:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from snippets.models import Snippet
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['GET'])
def snippet_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Ensure to import Response from rest_framework.response and use it in your views for a more streamlined integration with Django Rest Framework.